# Widget to start Activity

Tags: android

I have developed a widget. It contains image buttons.
I can select a city name(in the button) and it will open another application developed by me which will display the above city in map.

I have created the activity and the widget but don't know how to launch the application from the widget and how we can pass the city name to the application

Comment: No need to open a new application every time :):).Just open or start a new Activity

Comment: sorry no edit text needed............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last i found the way

```
Intent theActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
.setComponent(new ComponentName("your.pkgname", "com.pkgname.ScreenName"));
```

this open the application with the specified page

Answer (score 0):

You can open the app screen from widget by bleow code..and for trasfer data from widget to app...u need to first save data to preference and then use it in app.

```
public class WatchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )
    {

         Intent intent = new Intent(context, show.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout );
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.root, pendingIntent);

        watchWidget = new ComponentName( context, WatchWidget.class );
```